# HttpClient missing from .Net portable subset while creating PCL in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, httpclient, portable-class-library

I have created a Portable class library in Xamarin and want to use it for an android app. I want to use the `HttpClient` within this PCL. I have added the `Microsoft Http Client libraries` from the NuGet Package manager. I can now see the `.Net portable subset` added to my references. But somehow I still cannot use the `HttpClient` and it does not show in the .Net portable subset as well.

Also, my `Current profile` of the PCL is `4.0-Profile 158`. If I change the profile to 4.5, Xamarin crashes and does not open the solution

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: What platforms do you want to target? If you need iOS and Android only and _no_ WP8, select .NET45, iOS, Android and Windows 8 Store Apps. That will give you `HttpClient` without having to add anything from Nuget.

Comment: @Krumelur I tried doing that but Xamarin crashes as soon as i change it to 4.5 n the solution never opens after tht

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple solution is to target .NET 4.5, Windows Store apps (Windows 8.1), Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Android (4.5-Profile7).  Then you won't need the HttpClient NuGet package to get those APIs.

If Xamarin is crashing when you try to select a 4.5 profile, please make sure you're using the latest version and then report the bug with details about how to repro it and what happens.

Also the HttpClient NuGet package should allow you to use HttpClient from PCL profile 158.  Make sure you're using the latest version of NuGet.  ".NET Portable Subset" should always appear in your references for a PCL, that's not related to the NuGet package.  When you install the HttpClient NuGet package, you should also see references to System.Net.Http and other assemblies in your references.