# Xamarin Error on Signed Assembly

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I developed and built my application using F# and  C# successfully using Xamarin Mac.

It was all fine and finished development, until I switched to App Store compilation. The compilation goes fine, and signs all the assemblies. However when I run the application, the point where it reaches my F# library, throws an exception of

**Could not bind function op_Division in type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators**

Alternative:
**Could not bind function {0} in type {1}**
whichever the first external call is

I tried other variations, and I get the same error with different functions and different assemblies. It looks like the assemblies are not linked to the library, not sure if that's possible since the compilation succeeded and that's the point with strongly typing?

I didn't see this exception during development and test.

Does anyone know why same code work fine on debug and release, but not on app store compiled (all it does it signs assemblies with developer key), and any idea for resolution?

Comment: Sounds like the linker has removed that function. You should contact Xamarin support to do more troubleshooting.

Comment: See the section here on skipping assemblies. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/  That may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the linker was over optimising, and removing it from the assembly.

Changing "Linker Behavior." to  "Link Framework SDKs Only." rather than "Link All" fixes the issue.

Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about AppStore compilation, but it sounds like the tool Xamarin is using to bundle the app is missing a reference to the F# libraries.

Similar to this?
[HttpClient missing from .Net portable subset while creating PCL in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844262/httpclient-missing-from-net-portable-subset-while-creating-pcl-in-xamarin)

Comment: Thanks. I can't actually decide wheter it is a Xamarin bug or F# bug. I actually looked at the compiled package directory, and all the dlls are included in the package. I will try to touch the libraries from the main application just in case the compiler does some premature optimisation or something, and it doesn't link