# Exception calling PutAsJsonAsync from Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to write a small test application using WebApi. I have it mostly working, I am able to get data from my web service and display it in Android.

I added a button, and used the same code that I had used in my Winforms test client:

```
   async void buttonSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
        Customer data = new Customer () {
        Surname = editSurname.Text,
        GivenName = editGivenName.Text};

        var result = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("http://10.0.0.4/WebApplication1/api/Customers/2", data);
       if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode ) {
       labelStatus.Text = "Saved";
       }
    }
```

This works fine in the Windows Forms test app, but in the Xamarin app I get an exception on client.PutAsJsonAsync:

E/mono-rt ( 7519): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[T]' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Any suggestions? Using Xamarin 3.

edit:

It works if I format the content manually:

```
        string sData =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(sData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,  "application/json") ;
        var result = await client.PutAsync("http://10.0.0.4/WebApplication1/api/Customers/2",content);
```

I have all the references correct, as far as I can see. I used the WebApi Client nuget package.

References:

```
Newtonsoft.Json
System.Net.Http
System.Net.Http.Extensions
System.Net.Http.Formatting
System.Net.Http.Primitives
```

Comment: I have the same issue but with `PostAsAsync()`, have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @markmnl: It seems to be related to the HttpClient PCL libs availability. Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844262/httpclient-missing-from-net-portable-subset-while-creating-pcl-in-xamarin

Comment: @marceln I am not sure that is the problem - I can see the lib fine - I am using the HttpClient from the NuGet package for the PCL - everything compiles and it only fails when running on Android after running the `PostAsJsonAsync()` method... The OP's workaround does work for me in the interim though now I am getting network is unreachable but that is another problem

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve it either - I am using it the long way at the moment.

Comment: This also happens for me. Oddly enough it is just the call to Logout() that does this. Other calls to PostAsJsonAsync() work fine. I can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Did anyone have any luck solving this? Just come across the issue too using PostAsync in a PCL on Android.

Comment: For others that have the same issue, it might help if we can categorize the issue some. Consider letting others know if you are using .NET, Xamarin, or Mono.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the following Nuget packages to all the projects that reference your HttpClient project

1. Microsoft.Bcl.Build
2. Microsoft.Bcl

These are the warnings from Visual Studio when I built my project and after I done that, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

**Serialize your data into a JSON string like this:**

```
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                    response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The overload list for the `System.Net.Http.PutAsJsonAsync` method on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.putasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx) only shows overloads that contain three or four parameters. In your example, I see two that you are passing. It appears correct to be able to leave out the `HttpClient` parameter when called as a instance from `HttpClient` based on the code examples from MSDN.

However, with Xamarin it was built as a fork of MonoDevelop. MonoDevelop uses the Mono Framework which is a port of the .NET Framework. Due to that difference, I am interested if a bug should be opened for Mono, MonoDevelop, or Xamarin.

Back to the overload methods list though, I recommend trying to use one of these overloads.

- PutAsJsonAsync(HttpClient, String, T)
- PutAsJsonAsync(HttpClient, Uri, T)
- PutAsJsonAsync(HttpClient, String, T, CancellationToken)
- PutAsJsonAsync(HttpClient, Uri, T, CancellationToken)

I recommend trying to pass the `HttpClient` to the `PutAsJsonAsync` method without `PutAsJsonAsync` being called from an instance of `HttpClient`.

BTW, this is not a guaranteed solution, for it was simply too much information to put into comments. Hope this helps.